# Unable to open binary file that exists

Tags: c++, linux, file-io, binary

I can't open that specific file (got it from [here](http://corpus-texmex.irisa.fr/), it is inside the gist.tar.gz), I can however open the query file for example and read it properly. What's wrong? Maybe the problem lies in the fact that the file is too big for me? But I thought that if this was the case I could open it and then receive a `bad_alloc` or something.

Here is what happens:

```
samaras@samaras-A15:~/parallel/rkd_forest/code$ ./rkd_sam 
I/O error : Unable to open the file ../Datasets/gist/gist_base.fvecs
samaras@samaras-A15:~/parallel/rkd_forest/code$ cd ../Datasets/gist/
samaras@samaras-A15:~/parallel/rkd_forest/Datasets/gist$ ls
gist_base.fvecs  gist_groundtruth.ivecs  gist_learn.fvecs  gist_query.fvecs
```

Here is my code (should be OK):

```
FILE* fid;
fid = fopen(filename, "rb");
if (!fid)
  printf("I/O error : Unable to open the file %s\n", filename);
```

Here are the permissions of the file:
[image]

and its size is 3.8 GB (3,844,000,000 bytes) and I **know** that this dataset is [too big for this computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309681/what-stdbad-alloc-am-i-out-of-memory).

As a result I [moved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438698/run-an-executable-from-ubuntu-to-debian) to another machine, but I am getting the very same problem.

The memory there (it is 64 bits, while my pc runs on 32 bits):

```
gsamaras@geomcomp:~/Desktop/code$ free -mt
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3949       3842        106          0        173       3186
-/+ buffers/cache:        483       3466
Swap:        10867         59      10808
Total:       14816       3901      10914
```

---

`std::cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;`

gave

`Error: Value too large for defined data type`

---

`printf("|%s|\n", filename);`

gave

`|../Datasets/gist/gist_base.fvecs|`

and the value is taken from cmd and in the code I am doing this:

`readDivisionSpacefvecs<FT>(test, N, D, argv[8]); // in main()`

and then

```
void readDivisionSpacefvecs(Division_Euclidean_space<T>& ds, int& N, int& D, char* filename) {
  FILE* fid;
  fid = fopen(filename, "rb");
  printf("|%s|\n", filename);
  if (!fid) {
    printf("I/O error : Unable to open the file %s\n", filename);
    std::cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
  }
  ...
}
```

I also tried to move the folder which contains the dataset, but I got the same result!

Comment: Use e.g. [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strerror) to find out the actual error.

Comment: print the error code (errno) or use a C function to look up the error text.  Opening a file does not fail simply because a file is too large.  There is something else wrong.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg edited. I wonder what jim!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am not sure this is the issue, edited.

Comment: Misread the error, will post an answer.

Comment: try compiling the code with these options to compiler `-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1` and `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`, example `gxx -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`

Comment: @Sridhar just answered, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get is `EOVERFLOW`, which is you read [the `open` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) means

> *`pathname`* refers to a regular file that is too large to be
>   opened.  The usual scenario here is that an application
>   compiled on a 32-bit platform without *`-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`*
>   tried to open a file whose size exceeds (1<<31)-1 bytes; see
>   also `O_LARGEFILE` above.  This is the error specified by
>   POSIX.1-2001; in kernels before 2.6.24, Linux gave the error
>   `EFBIG` for this case.

What that means is that you're on a 32-bit platform and try open a file that's simply to big to be handle without special considerations.

Either recompile your program with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` or use the `open` call directly with the `O_LARGEFILE` flag.

Comment: It worked, but unfortunately, I could not satisfy me purpose. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447736/same-memory-limitation-to-a-bigger-machine

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the program tries to open the file in the current directory (`code`), while the file is in another one (`Datasets/gist'). You did not provide the value of the`filename` variable, but it should contain the full path to the file for correct work.

You can try

```
cd ../Datasets/gist/
../../code/rkd_sam
```

This should work if `filename` contains only the basename without any path.

The size of the file does not matter at all as far as `fopen()` is concerned.

Comment: Tried that, same result.

Comment: Please provide the code setting the `filename` and print the value of this variable before `fopen()`.

Comment: Edited Mike, see my post.

Comment: Ok, the code assumes that at the moment of `fopen()` call the current working directory is `code`, which is probably not the case for some reason (e.g. a call to `chdir()` somewhere). As a quick fix, you can try specifying the absolute path, like `filename="/home/gsamaras/Desktop/Datasets/gist/gist_base.fvecs";`. This should work; you can find out what goes on with relative paths later.